# Save browsed pages during a session

Tags: asp.net

I want to save the page url, to a log file for example, that a user browses during a session and suggest him/her next time. What's the best scenario?

Comment: save that in a `cookie`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct scenario is to connect the user cookie with his data on a database on server and there keep the last visiting page.

An alternative for a site with few pages (and not database), is to have a number for each of your page and save this number only on the cookie, and then know what page to show base on this page number. Eg the 56 is for page contact.aspx

So the next time it will visit your page you find that parameter and make your suggestion.

To save the full url page on the cookie is something that I do not suggest because you make the cookie too big in size and that can lead to other problems (think that all cookies are follow the user on all calls, even the calls to see an image).

Of course you need to make this suggestions only for new sessions - and if the user is not on the same page. Think also what happens if a user have open 10 pages of your site opens and the session ends on all after some time of inactivity... Think again the user interface, the common way for that is the full history of what he see at the end of the page.

Comment: I think I have to implement this method(s) in OnLoad and/or OnInit events, so, can this reduces the performance?

Comment: @Mazdak No I do not think that reduces the performance, the read of the cookie for sure is not, the write of the cookie is something that I need to test - but nooo I do not think, is one more parameter to the browser... for sure is not the bottleneck of the speed.

Comment: And, if I have some dynamic pages, how I can assign a number to each pages? EG article.aspx?articleId=X,X is a variable??

Comment: @Mazdak The assign a number to each page is a trick to "zip" the data. You done that on a static list with variables on your code, eg: Dictionary<int,string> ListPages = new Dictionary<int,string>(); ListPages.Add(1, "article.aspx"). Now if you have the article id and you use it for change articles, yes this is one more way. Eg to save 1.34, where 1 is for articles, 34 is the ids